# Form autosubmit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel-4

blade.php

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script language"javascript" type"text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".view_parent_furnace_boiler").droppable();
});
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".device-container").draggable(
      {

      grid: [10, 10],
        containment: "#picture_container",

        stop: function(){

      /*finding the DMI' id*/
            var elementID = $(this).attr('id');
            var  elementID = elementID.split(",");
            var parent = $(this).parent();

      /*finding the x and y position percentage based on the container*/
            var xPosition = parseInt($(this).css('left'))/parent.width()*100+"%";
            var yPosition = parseInt($(this).css('top'))/parent.height()*100+"%";

            /*assigning the div id to variable for further display and debugging purpose*/
            for (var k = 0; k < elementID.length; k++) {
                var device_id = elementID[0];
                var command   = elementID[1];
                var map_id    = elementID[2];
            }

            /*assigining values to variables*/
            $('#test').val(device_id +',' + ' ' + command + ',' + ' ' + map_id);
            $('#device_id').val(device_id);
            $('#command').val(command);
            $('#map_id').val(map_id);
            $('#PositionX').val(xPosition);
            $('#PositionY').val(yPosition);
        },
        revert: 'invalid'
    });
}); 
</script>
```

here is my form

```
{{Form::open()}}
<div>
  <div class="well">

    {{ Form::text('device_id', '',  ['id'=>'device_id', 'style'=>'color:black']) }}
    {{ Form::text('command', '',    ['id'=>'command', 'style'=>'color:black']) }}
    {{ Form::text('map_id', '',     ['id'=>'map_id', 'style'=>'color:black']) }}
    {{ Form::text('x_position', '', ['id'=>'PositionX', 'style'=>'color:black']) }}
    {{ Form::text('y_position', '', ['id'=>'PositionY', 'style'=>'color:black']) }}


    {{ Form::submit('Save','', ['style'=>'color:black'] ) }}

  </div>
</div>

{{Form::close()}}
```

BuildingController.php

```
if(count((array)Input::all()) ) {

  $dmi = DashboardMapItem::where('map_id', Input::get('map_id'))
    ->where('device_id', Input::get('device_id'))
    ->where('command', Input::get('command'))
    ->first();
  // dd($dmi->toArray());
  $dmi->x_position = Input::get('x_position');
  $dmi->y_position = Input::get('y_position');
  if( $dmi->save() ) {
    Session::flash('success', 'DMI Updated');
    return Redirect::back();
  }
}
```

I would be very happy if anyone outthere help me,

I am trying to do autosubmit instead of a submit button itself. I have been looking arround but i could not find a solution. I tried to use ajax but couldnt figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by auto-submit? It would be great if you can be more clear.

Comment: I have a background picture and i display some elements with some properties on it. I want to move those elements within an container and would like to save the x and y positions back to the table. Submit button works fine but i have to hit submit button before moving other element.

Comment: i just uploaded the a picture of the page. here is the elements i am talking about http://imgur.com/wfug4N1. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try something like that.
What problem exactly do you have with AJAX?

```
$('#yourform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: form.prop('method'),
        url: form.prop('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),

        success: function(result) {
        alert('success');
        }
    }
    });

});
```

...and I'd just add this at the end of your `stop` event:

```
$('#yourform').submit();
```

Edit: Of course you need also to send proper response from your controller:

```
return Response::json('success', 200);
```

Comment: I am sorry i got back late! if i add the function, the query code does not work. why do you think? the elements does not move when i add your code!!